# Update Rejections in Internal Test Track

Tags: android, google-play-console

Currently our update getting rejected because of Intent Redirection Vulnerability. [Support Link](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en)

Google Support is not giving us any method/class or package name to address our issue.
So we did try their answer with very little information, but update kept getting rejected.

Google states (one of their email);
*"This rejection doesn't Impact the standing of your Google Play Developer Account, but repeated violations can result in the suspension of this app or your Google Play Developer account."*

First Question; I am wondering, getting rejects counts as violation? If it is, i would like know is there a way to send my app to the review process without any negative consequence.

Second Question; I looked up about rejections and suspensions in Interntal Test Track(or related to internal test track) but couldn't find a solid information.
Should we keep trying to solve the issue without expecting to get suspended by Google.

Answer (score 0):

About this;
I couldn't find an answer to my questions but we found out how Google Play Tracks works. Maybe this would help to a hopeless android developer who suffers from google play console polices

Currently;

- If you have issued or non-compliant apk/aab in one of your Track(Internal/Alpha/Beta or Production), your new versions will be rejected until you fix the issued track.

For example; Lets assume your current **Production** version, lets say `versionCode=1`, violates one of the Google Play policy, and lets assume you have a fix in your `versionCode=2`. If you try send `versionCode=2` update to **Internal**/**Alpha** or **Beta**, that update will most likely get rejected(or it appears like that on Console). Actually it is not rejected, it is just bad UX. Google Play Support states the issued apk `versionCodes` in their Notification Mail. Why this is happening? Because Google Play checks all the tracks, not the track you just sent your update. It seems like all tracks depended to each other so if you got rejected or have violating version on any track, that will most likely block your other tracks.

This becomes an issue if you are using other distribution tracks, In our case we don't want to send our new versions directly to release track.

Comment: In your example, do you mean Console showed "rejected" for versionCode 2? If so, that's really confusing to developers.

Comment: exactly, console gives misleading information about our apk or bundles, best way to avoid this kind of situation is to check version codes in rejection mail or rejection detail

Comment: Do you mean Console showed "rejected" for versionCode 2 but the rejection mail showed for versionCode 1?
Both are not reasonable because versionCode 2 was not really rejected and versionCode 1 should have rejection mail before. Do you mean they sent 2nd rejection mail but it's repetitive for versionCode 1?